# I can't test on my smartphone

Tags: android, smartphone

i was develop an smartphone game and when i test on android studio at AVD, it works, but when i test it at my device it just shut down and i don't know why it is.

i just want to look at log file but i can't find it.

```
android 
{
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "seaweed.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

i was test at AVD at api level 24, and my device's api level is 19.
so i think that it might happen because of api level but i can't realize it.

Comment: If the app crashes, please add the logs. You can use the following command to get them : Linux: adb logcat | grep AndroidRuntime
Windows: adb logcat | find "AndroidRuntime"

Comment: check the logcat and post the error/exception stack trace to get more relavant answers

Comment: Post your logcat

Comment: Thanks, now i can see my logcat i think adb does not installed.
i will try by my error and if it doesn't work, i will ask again

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this/23353174#23353174